# Loading MVC webgrid content second time not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have a webgrid there i am trying to bind IDictionary. I dont have any issue in binding first time. I am facing difficulty in the second time. I am getting the result in the model and it not refreshing the grid content second time. Trying to populate the grid data by dropdown value change. First time i am loading on menu click.

Here is my controller code. In the result i have the list of values. I am facing issue in binding it in webgrid after ajax call second time.

```
  public List<IDictionary> GetHotelingList(int floorId)
        {
            var model = new List<IDictionary>();

            using (var context = new FloorContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    model = ListHotelingByFloorId(context, floorId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            return model;
        }
```

This is my ajax call

```
$("#floor").bind("change", function () {

            var facilityId = parseInt($("#FacilityDropDown option:selected").val());
            var floorId = parseInt($("#floor option:selected").val());
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Floor/GetHotelingList',
                cache: false,
                data: { floorId: floorId },
                success: function (data) {
                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                error: function () {
                    if (facilityName.indexOf('-') != -1) {
                        $('#floor').empty();
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                        alert("error in generating floor");
                }
            });
        });
```

Code for binding in the grid.

```
@using System.Dynamic
@model List<System.Collections.IDictionary>

@{
    var result = new List<dynamic>();


    foreach (var emprow in Model)
    {
        var row = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();
        var eachEmpRow = (Dictionary<string, object>)emprow;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in eachEmpRow)
        {
            row.Add(keyValuePair);
        }
        result.Add(row);
    }
    var grid = new WebGrid(result, rowsPerPage: 50, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grdHoteling");
}
```

Any help please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make a container div in main view from where you call ajax and load result in that div:

```
<div id="GridContainer">
// load you view first time here
</div>
```

and on ajax call update content of this div in success call back of ajax:

```
 success: function (data) {
                 $("#GridContainer").html(data);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks its refreshing the grid. But the problem now is its refreshing the entire page and creating the control n number of times. each time i am seeing one new drop down added in the page

Comment: Any idea please? its adding the control again and again except the grid

Comment: you need to just add the grid control in container div

Comment: ya i have a div like this  <div id="gridContent">

            @if (@Model != null)
            {
                @grid.GetHtml(
                htmlAttributes: new { id = "grdHoteling" },
                tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)
            }
        </div>

Comment: make a partial view for grid control, your view is not partial view so it is rendering whole page every time